# I cannot add an image in aframe

Tags: aframe

I am trying to wrap my head around this. I have used aframe for a few other things with no problem. I am trying to get an image to display on aframe. This is the code I am using.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <a-scene>
            <a-assets>
                <img id="my-image" src="assets/cowboy.jpg">
            </a-assets>

            <!-- Using the asset management system. -->
            <a-image src="#my-image" width="16" height="9"></a-image>

            <!-- Defining the URL inline. Not recommended but more comfortable for web developers. -->
            <!--<a-image src="assets/cowboy.jpg" width="16" height="9"></a-image>-->
        </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the glitch page hosting this code: https://nonstop-bramble-leaf.glitch.me

The code is taken directly from aframe.io. I have tried using imaged hosted online and also using assets uploaded to glitch. This is a total noob question but please help me understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The assets on glitch aren't a usable subdirectory,

```
<img id="my-image" src="assets/cowboy.jpg">
```

You have to go to the assets folder, click on an asset, copy the actual URL:

```
<img id="my-image" src="https://cdn.glitch.com/59a9c00b-1ef0-4ec8-8cb6-8313232369e0%2Fcowboy.jpg">
```

And it [should be working properly](https://stack-65818826.glitch.me/).